# Python get sublists

Tags: python

I've a very simple question about python and lists.

I need to cycle trough a list and get sublists of a fixed lenght, spanning from the beginning to the end. To be more clear:

```
    def get_sublists( length ):
            # sublist routine

    list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

    sublist_len = 3

    print get_sublists( sublist_len )
```

this should return something like this:

```
    [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    [ 2, 3, 4 ]
    [ 3, 4, 5 ]
    [ 4, 5, 6 ]
    [ 5, 6, 7 ]
```

Is there any simple and elegant approach to do this in python?

Comment: Maybe you saw the discussion below @Martijn Pieters' answer. It's a good idea to use some other variable name than `list`, since `list` is a built-in type which will be masked if you have a variable with the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a loop and yield slices:

```
def get_sublists(length):
    for i in range(len(lst) - length + 1)
        yield lst[i:i + length]
```

or, if you must return a list:

```
def get_sublists(length):
    return [lst[i:i + length] for i in range(len(lst) - length + 1)]
```

Comment: do you have a favorite in guide to using yield statements?

Comment: Isn't `lst` supposed to be `list`?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: No, because it is never a good idea to use `list` as a variable name, that'd mask the built-in type.

Comment: How do you apply this to a list?  I imagine this modification is needed `get_sublists(lst, length)` to pass in a specific list.

Comment: @pylang: just pass in a specific list, yes. Making `lst` an argument instead of a closure or global is perfectly fine and works.

Answer (score 3):

```
[alist[i:i+3] for i in range(len(alist)-2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the [itertools pairwise recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
from itertools import izip, tee
def nwise(iterable, n):
    z = tee(iterable, n)
    for i, x in enumerate(z):
            for k in range(i):
                    next(x)
    return izip(*z)

for l in nwise(iter([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]), 3):
    print l

# Output
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(5, 6, 7)
```

**Description**: Three iterators are teed and enumerated `0`, `1`, `2`. These serve as columns in the output that are advanced `i` times, which effectively moves the columns "up" by `i`.  The columns are zipped as rows up to the length of the shortest iterable (the last column which terminates at `7`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed):

```
import more_itertools as mit

lst = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

list(mit.windowed(lst, 3))
# [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py) for the specific implementation.